# What is the equivalent of Delphi unit in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, namespaces

I'm a Delphi programmer and I want to know what's the same thing as Delphi unit in C#? Can anyone give a sample C# unit with one or two function then how to call those functions? I mean like Delphi unit in C# that have some functions that I use them every time by importing them in import section.

Comment: There is a project type 'class library'. Build one, add to project, add namespace. Done..And just as in Delphi: Try to keep them stable :-)

Comment: A Delphi unit is, for all practical purposes, a source file and a (sub)namespace, so make your choice. C# doesn't have standalone functions, so you'll have to make them (probably static) methods of a class, just like you can do in Delphi. IIRC, in Delphi for .NET, the generated .NET class name for standalone functions was generally the name of the Delphi unit.

Comment: C# has nothing directly equivalent to Delphi units. Different languages approach problems in different ways. Rather than trying to apply your delphi solution to a problem, try to approach the problem from a C# way, using the idiom of that language.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously C# doesn't have units as such; units are just a bunch of types, constants and procedures that can be shared by several applications. You can get the same functionality through using classes or static classes in namespaces, and if you want to share them between applications, .NET has class libraries, which are assemblies that can be easily shared.

I'd suggest at this stage taking a trip though the C# documentation

[Classes (C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes))

[Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/)

Answer (score -1):

if you mean Importing Libraries to use  functions from your libraries like Delphi

```
uses unit1,unit2
```

it is

```
using unit1;
using unit2;
```

for example :

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

a sample:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class myclass
    {


        public static bool myfinction(string un)
        {
         boolean b
          ...
         Return b
        }

        public string Getmyhash(string aPassword)
        {
          
            return ...  
         }
   }
}
```

You can google for namespaces classes, Function and static function .